# Retrieval of multiple author affiliations using RISmed from Medline object

Tags: r, text-mining, pubmed

In using the RISmed- R-package for automating data(abstract/author/affiliation etc.) retrieval from Medline, I can't retrieve multiple affiliations using the Affiliation() method. Only a first author's affiliation is retrieved  even through multiple are available. From the https://www.nlm.nih.gov/bsd/mms/medlineelements.html#ad
it appears that after Dec 2014 multiple affiliations are included in the affiliation field. Analogously the Author() method retrieves a list that contains multiple data frames accounting for all author data. Does anyone know if the Affiliation() method can do the same?

For example:
In retrieving affiliations for : https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/28578058
note from the link that there are 4 different affiliations. When executing the code below only first one is returned:

```
      library(RISmed)
      RetrievePub <- EUtilsGet(28578058)

         #Retrieve authorship
         AData <- data.frame(Author(RetrievePub))
         Results_Authors = paste(paste(AData$ForeName, AData$LastName), 
          collapse = " | ") #flatten data frame into string
         print(Results_Authors)

         #Retrieve affiliation
         Results_PubAffiliation = Affiliation(RetrievePub)
         print(Results_PubAffiliation)
```

Comment: It would be easier to help if you provided a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with the code you have tried so far.

Comment: thanks, just added @MrFlick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RISmed Version 2.1.6 only returned the Affiliation for the first author. The latest version (2.1.7) now provides the list of all affiliations in the same order as the author list. This is now available at https://github.com/skoval/RISmed and can be installed with devtools. It should be available from CRAN in the next day or so.